# Qual a diferença quando se usa binary na cláusula where?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, binary

- O que é *Binary* e o que ele faz?
- Qual é a diferença gerada, quando se utiliza o *Binary* em uma *query* no *MySQL* e quando não utiliza o *Binary*?

`SELECT email, senha from login WHERE usuario = ? && senha = ?`

`SELECT email,senha from login WHERE BINARY usuario = ? && BINARY senha = ?`

- Existe alguma diferença em outros *SGBD's*, ou o *Binary* nem existe em outros *SGBD's*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, o select deveria ser assim:

```
  SELECT email, senha from login WHERE usuario = ? and senha = ?
```

e não assim:

```
  SELECT email, senha from login WHERE usuario = ? && senha = ?
```

**BINARY** não existe em outros SGBDs e no MySQL a sua função é forçar 
uma comparação exata, ou seja,  uma comparação **case-sensitive**, byte a byte.

```
SELECT 'senha' = 'seNha'  -- 1 - true

SELECT BINARY 'senha' = 'SeNha'  -- 2 - false
```

Outro uso é na criação da tabela, ao utilizar a palavra **BINARY** você força
que a comparação para aquela coluna seja `case-sensitive`, byte a byte.

Comment: No C#, JAVA, por exemplo, a sintaxe diz que o operador lógico AND deve ser escrito assim: `&&` e no PL/SQL, que é linguagem que os SGDBs entendem a sintaxe diz que deve ser escrito assim: `AND`